# Is it possible to specify a server name in Html.Actionlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have this scenario in an MVC 5 View.

```
<p>Welcome to Web App 1</p>

@*This link points to another Visual Studio MVC solution on the same localhost.*@

<p><a href="http://localhost:12392/Home/Index">Web app 2</a></p>
```

While I can use an HTML anchor tag, as I'm using in this example, is there a way I can use an HTML Helper? I'm looking [LinkExtensions.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) Method and do not see any overloads similar to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Web App 2","Index","Home",new { /* server name goes here?*/},null)
```

I know how to use the `RouteValues` parameter to indicate a desired `Area`, but I have not seen any examples to indicate a different solution or project. Is this even possible?

Comment: You could always make your own link helper. But if it's only a few times I'd just write out the anchor directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to use the RouteValues parameter to indicate a desired
>   Area, but I have not seen any examples to indicate a different
>   solution or project. Is this even possible?

The short answer is no, since Solution A has no way of knowing the routes / controllers / actions of Solution B.